# Clicking a input button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to have my Selenium Script click a input button off a website. For some reason everything i've tried hasn't worked. It seems like something very simple but its just not wokring for me.

Error:

```
    backupbidbutton.click()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Buttons html code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Place Backup Bid" class="bid-button place-backupbid-button" rel="placeBestBid" id="placeBackupBidButton">
```

My code: This is how i call for the button click.

```
    backupbidbutton = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').find('input', {'id':'placeBackupBidButton'})
    backupbidbutton.click()
```

i called for it using `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Comment: What is the exception trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use id, instead of soup and trying to get element from page source.

Code :

```
input_button =  driver.find_element_by_id("placeBackupBidButton")
input_button.click()
```

Make sure that this input should not be in any frame.